# Backbone.js refresh view without reloading page

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm using backbone.js and in a view I have the following view:

```
window.PersonListView = Backbone.View.extend({

initialize: function () {
    this.render();
},

render: function () {

    var people = this.model.models;

    $(this.el).html(this.template());                

    for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
        this.$('#peopleTable tbody').append(new PersonListItemView({model: people[i], no: i+1}).render().el);
    }

    this.$('#peopleTable').dataTable({"bAutoWidth": false,"iDisplayLength": 50});        

    return this;
}
});

window.PersonListItemView = Backbone.View.extend({

tagName: "tr",

initialize: function (options) {
    this.model.bind("change", this.render, this);
    this.model.bind("destroy", this.close, this);
    this.no = options.no;
    this.render();
},

render: function () {

    $(this.el).html(this.template({
            //people stuff
    }));

    return this;
},

events: {
    "click .delete"     : "deletePerson",
},

deletePerson: function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    if (confirm("Are you sure to delete the person?")) {            
        this.model.destroy({
            success: function () {
                location.reload();
            }
        });
    }

    return false;
}
```

});

This person is in a list of people and when they click delete I want to update the list WITHOUT reloading the entire site. How do I have to modify the view to do this?
Thanks!

Comment: You can just remove one item from list... Could you post your templates ?

Comment: ah that works nice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just remove one item from list,

```
deletePerson: function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (confirm("Are you sure to delete the person?")) {
        this.model.destroy({
            success: function() {
                $(event.currentTarget).closest('tr').remove();
            }
        });
    }

    return false;
}
```